# Pivot and aggregate large amount of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

| Place | Name | 2019-03-01 | 2019-03-02 | ... | 2021-03-02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paris | Sam | 2 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| Paris | Steve | 12 | 4 | ... | 0 |
| Dublin | Sam | 8 | 1 | ... | 0 |

I have something like hundreds of the date-named columns.
The `Name` column contains only Sam or Steve.

I want to create a 'Date' column that contains the dates previously in the date-named columns and create a `sum_SAM`and `sum_STEVE`columns filled with  the sum of the values for each one of Sam and Steve.

So I would get something like this :

| Place | Date | sum_SAM | sum_STEVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paris | 2019-03-01 | 2 | 12 |
| Dublin | 2019-03-01 | 8 | 0 |
| Paris | 2021-03-02 | 0 | 4 |
| Dublin | 2021-03-02 | 1 | 0 |

I guess I have to transpose the date-named columns into a new column named 'Date', and then group by place and Date, and sum it. But I really don't know how to do it.
The fact that there's a lot of the date-named columns scares me lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with

```
out = df.set_index(['Place','Name']).stack().sum(level=[0,1,2],axis=0).unstack(level=1)
```

Comment: I have ```ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape```

Comment: Works perfectly! But I have something like ```Paris/2019-03-01```in the row index instead of having it as 2 columns. Do you know how to solve this?
Thank you for your help :D

Comment: @Awans out = df.set_index(['Place','Name']).stack().sum(level=[0,1,2],axis=0).unstack(level=1).reset_index()

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have to work on the stack/unstack and pivot.